# Cannot Call form's public function in Main()?

Tags: c#

I apologize if this seems trivial but I cant seem to grasp this one. Other asked questions here are slightly different, so here is my question:

I have a **MainForm** that goes

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void activateButton()
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
    }
//........
```

I want to call `activateButton()` from `Main()` that goes

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Form myForm = new MainForm();
    Application.Run(myForm);
    myForm.activateButton() // error
}
```

Why can't the public method `activateButton()` be seen from `myForm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other commenters pointed out, you will have an error due to your variable being of type Form instead of MainForm.  But there is still another issue.  Once you call Application.Run(form), the application has entered the main message pump loop.  This is essentially an infinite while() loop that just checks for user input and handles Windows message dispatch (you can hook into this by overriding the form's WndProc method). So any code in Main after this will not be called until you close the form.

If you are trying to call the activateButton() method after your form opens, try calling it in the form's constructor, or better yet by overriding OnLoad() and calling it in there.

Comment: Wow, this is the exact problem I ran into, I fixed it like you said but didn't really know why. Thanks for showing that out so clear !

Answer (score 3):

The variable `myForm` is of type `Form`. If you declare it as `MainForm` you'll be able to access your method:

```
MainForm myForm = new MainForm();
myForm.activateButton() // No error.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MainForm myForm = new MainForm();
```

In your original code, the compile-time type is `Form`, so `activateButton` is not visible.